# Return Variable with break

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, line-breaks

I create a code which gives me back a variable. At the moment the variable gives back the values like value1, value2, ... in one line. But I need this with breaks 
Value1
Value2
...

Here is my code

```
while (test[i]) {
          var total = 0;
          var spielerName = '';

          Spieltag.find({SpielerID: test[i]}).map(function(doc) {
             total += doc.Note;
          });
          Playerslist.find({SpielerID: test[i]}).map(function(doc) {
             spielerName += doc.Name;
          });

          spielerPkt += spielerName + ": " + total + ", ";
          i++;
        }
        return spielerPkt;
```

In html this is simple in the body with {{TemplateFunction}}
Can I make an adjustment in html to get my needs or must I change my while loop?

Comment: use [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) to add in line breaks in html, or surround whole text in [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) if it already includes line breaks (like `\n`)

Comment: ```spielerPkt += spielerName + ": " + total + ", " + "\n";```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a line break by adding `\n` to the string.